# Found a lot of 404 Html Pages in Google Analytics, how to fix it?

Tags: 404

I have found some 404 Html pages in my google analytics account, which have a good amount of traffic. But when I am checking my website or indexed pages, I can't see any missing pages myself when I am browsing my site? Is this 404s an urgent issue that needs to be fixed immediately? If I just leave them as missing pages, would that cause more problems afterward?
[image]

Comment: Do you have custom 404 handler with the GA snippet installed on it?   Most sites don't use GA on their 404 pages.

Comment: I didn't have 404 handler, is it a plugin?

Comment: You can configure your web server to use a custom HTML page or a custom script for 404 errors.  See [What is a Custom 404 Page and Why Do You Need One?](https://smallbiztrends.com/2016/03/what-is-a-custom-404-page.html)

Comment: These should be redirected properly if the pages have simply changed, or left alone if they legitimately don't exist anymore.

Comment: What CMS are you using? WordPress, Jekyll...?

Comment: Hi Unix, I use WordPress

Comment: Many WordPress themes customize the 404 page as part of the theme.  What theme are you using?